# What is the idiomatic way to define a crate that can use one of multiple "backends" to achieve what it needs to do?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I'm writing a Rust [library](https://github.com/btzy/nfde-rs) that wraps around some platform-specific API calls (in this case, to open the file picker).

On Linux, there are two ways ("backends") to open the file picker - using GTK or using Portals (what they actually are doesn't matter very much for the purposes of this question - just think of them as two different system libraries that one can use to open the file picker).  Typically, the choice depends on whether the application developer wants portability (GTK) or "native"-ness (Portal), and the choice of backend affects the libraries that my library needs to link (specified in build.rs).  It is impossible to use both, since the interface exposed to the user is identical (and that's the point - the code calling my library shouldn't have to care about what backend is being used, and only link with one of the system libraries).

How should one write the Cargo.toml file to allow the user of my library to pick the backend they want?

In CMake, this would typically look like the following:

```
set(BACKEND "GTK" CACHE STRING "Select the backend (GTK or Portal)")
```

In Cargo, we have "[features](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/features.html)".  However, features can only be "enabled" or "disabled", and semantically features seem to be meant to conditionally *add* code into the library to be compiled.  While there's a section about mutually exclusive features, it looks very much like a hack, and the other options don't seem to be ideal either.

Ideally, if other libraries have a dependency on my library, they shouldn't need to (or even try to) select the desired backend.  The developer of the final executable application should be the one making the decision.

Comment: I have to agree that this is something that Rust is still lacking a bit. But with Rust's premise of being stable and reliable, it's hard to achieve.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure if this is idiomatic, but I would tackle your problem like this:

- Create a `trait` describing the desired functionality of your backends.
- Create a `struct` that contains all the state of your library.
- Require the actual backend to be passed into your library via constructor argument (as trait object) and store it in the state struct
- If other libraries need to use your library, pass said state struct to them via reference or similar

Alternatively:

- Create a `trait` describing the desired functionality of your backends.
- Create a static `Option<dyn BackendTrait>` in your library and an initialization function that needs to be called at the beginning of `main` that sets the desired backend.

Either way, the actual backends can then be delivered in separate crates and the final executable is responsible for linking the correct one and setting it at runtime.

Comment: This isn't very satisfactory though, the main point of wanting the option in Cargo in that we don't need to have dead code in the final executable or have useless runtime dependencies in it.  This solution is more suitable when we want to compile both backends into the final executable, and have the end user choose the backend at runtime.

Comment: @Bernard A trait implementation that is not used (dead code) will not appear in the executable.

Comment: As far as I can tell, you still need to import both backend crates, which means that both proposed solutions here will be dynamically linked to a useless shared library.  The first solution won't have dead code included in the executable, but the second one might emit the dead code (i.e. code for the backend library that the initialization function did not construct) unless link time optimization is amazing enough to devirtualize the virtual function (the dyn trait).

Comment: No, you only have to import the backend crate that gets used in the end. You instantiate the backend object and pass it to the library. The library has no dependencies to the backend crates, it's a runtime dependency injection.

Answer (score 0):

It is true that [features should be additive](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/features.html#feature-unification), and the current solution is somewhat lacking. But most libaries when they need to select between two options (a common case is between two or more async runtimes) create *two* features, say named `gtk` and `portals`, then let the user pick one. You can sure the following code to ensure a compilation error if more or less than one is enabled:

```rust
#[cfg(not(any(
    all(feature = "gtk", not(feature = "portals")),
    all(feature = "portals", not(feature = "gtk")),
)))]
compile_error!("only one, and exactly one of the features `gtk` and `portals` must be enabled.");
```

You can also e.g. enable `gtk` by default and disable `portals`:

```ini
[features]
default = ["gtk"]
gtk = []
portals = []
```

But still feature unification will fail if two dependencies choose the opposite backends.

Comment: Yeah, I was thinking of doing this but it's really awkward.  You'd have to select the correct option in every crate on the list.  Furthermore, if gtk is the default, then to use portals you'd have to remember to disable default features.